# iPhone SDK: Append NSString and Count Data

Tags: xcode, arrays, loops, nsstring

The web service that I am accessing returns this values:

```
A1;A2;A3;A4;A5;B2;B10;B11;B12;
```

I want to get the total count of all the data returned separated by `;`. How can I do this? I'm thinking of doing a loop inside the string, get the value before `;` but getting confused on how to properly run the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many string functions and you can use one of them, that is **componentsSeparatedByString**.

Considering that above mentioned return value is a NSString.

```
NSString *strResponse = @"A1;A2;A3;A4;A5;B2;B10;B11;B12;";
NSArray *arCount = [strResponse componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
NSLog(@"Total objects in response is: %d", [arCount count]);
```